# How can I store byte[]'s in a Vector in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, vector, byte

I'm reading a binary file and storing each record into a **byte[]**.  Now I'd like to collect these records into a Java **Vector**.  (So that it can grow indefinitely.)  But **Vector** takes **Objects**, not primitives (or arrays of primitives, as far as I can tell).

Is there way to "box" an array of primitives, or am I going to have to rewrite my code to turn my arrays into **Arrays** and my bytes into **Bytes**?

I tried concatenating the bytes into a **String**, but that failed miserable, due to **String.append()**'s propensity to treat my bytes as ints and convert them into String-y decimal representations!!

Comment: Are you trying to convert a `byte[]` into a `Vector` or convert your code that uses `byte[]` to user `Vector` instead? Any reason you don't want to use `List<Byte>`?

Comment: "or arrays of primitives, as far as I can tell" - How do you tell? Did you try it? Because you can and it will work. `List<byte[]> recordList = new ArrayList<byte[]>();` Don't use Vector.

Comment: @Gabe: sorry for the confusion - I wanted a Vector<byte[]>.
@Wolfcastle: see below; I *thought* I'd tried it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`byte[]` is-an `Object` (all arrays are, even primitive ones).  There is nothing stopping you from adding a `byte[]` to a `Vector`.

```
Vector<byte[]> records = new Vector<byte[]>();
byte[] firstRecord = readRecord();
records.add(firstRecord);
```

Though it doesn't smell like a good design.  Also, you should favour passing around `List` (the interface) over passing around a `Vector` (a concrete implementation of `List`).

Comment: +1 for answering the actual question. I misread it at first as well.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted: to store each byte[] as an element of Vector.  Apologies for being less-than-clear in my original post.

I thought that I had already tried coding Vector<byte[]> but got dinged by Eclipse's incremental compiler.  Perhaps there was something else wrong, or I'm simply misremembering.

I'll now take a look at List vs. Vector.

Comment: Okay, I'm stumped.  I declared: List<byte[]> foo; as an instance variable, but I'm unable to instantiate it!  I think the problem is that List<> is only an interface, correct?  I'm not sure what I have to do at this point to have a useable list of byte arrays.

Comment: @Chap: Yes, `List` is an interface.  Popular implementations are `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`, and an implementation is what you should instantiate (`List<...> list = new ArrayList<...>()`).  With polymorphism you can assign an instance of a class to any superclass or interface.  `Vector` is an implementation of `List` as well, but it has fallen out of favour as it has some legacy downsides.

Comment: That is helpful; I will study up on this aspect of Java - namely, declaring a variable as simply an interface.  (Let me know how to "credit" you for the above, if possible.)

Comment: With java <7, you have to use the full `List<byte[]> records = new ArrayList<byte[]>();`

With java 7-9, the ideal declaration is `List<byte[]> records = new ArrayList<>();` - ArrayList tends to be more performant and efficient except for cases where you don't remove items in the middle of the list.  

With java 10+, it's probably a little clearer to say `var records = new ArrayList<byte[]>();`

Answer (score 1):

You can add all the bytes in a byte[] to a Vector<Byte> by looping through each byte.

However, I wouldn't suggest you use Vector as it is a legacy class which was replaced in Java 1.2 (1998)

You can use an ArrayList instead, but this will use 4-16 times as much memory as the original byte[].

If you cannot use TByteArrayList, I suggest you use ByteArrayOutputStream and ByteArrayInputStream.

Comment: Vector was not replaced, it was refactored to be part of Collections Framework - `As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the List interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, Vector is synchronized.`

Comment: @nathansizemore You can use Collections.synschronizedList().  Vector is a legacy collection IMHO, for when there is a cleaner alternative.

Comment: I was mistaken, Java 8 docs actually are updated to recommend `ArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
byte[] byteArr = new byte[]{0x41, 0x43};
List<byte[]> listBytes = Arrays.asList(byteArr); // to get a list
List<byte[]> list = new Vector<byte[]>(listBytes); // to instantiate a vector
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.get(0)));
```

#### Update (Based on your comments)

```
List<byte[]> l = new Vector<byte[]>(); // to instantiate a vector
l.add(new byte[]{0x51, 0x52});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(l.get(0)));
```

#### OUTPUT

```
[81, 82]
```

Comment: No, you really can't.  Try it, see what you get.

Comment: @Mark: Yes realized and fixed.

Comment: I'm having a hard time with List<byte[]>.  I declared it, as you did in line 2, but .. how do you initialize it to an empty List?  And, is it possible to write listBytes.add(new byte[]{0x51, 0x52}) to add another byte[] to the List?  (Note I've also asked @Mark similar question, above)

Comment: @Chap: I don't see any problem in what you're trying to do. Please see Update section above.

Comment: Thanks - earlier I was trying **List<byte[]> l = new List<byte[]>();** .. now understand I have to instantiate with something concrete that _implements_ List interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely cannot convert the byte's into Bytes, then you might look into a primitive collection library such as [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/). It was written for high performance scientific stuff but it has primitive collection types that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I catch what u mean,
***Yes*** it is impossible to put array of somethings into a Vector or even into ArrayList as one element, let me explain why the following code is completely right but we misunderstand it

```
Vector<byte[]> records = new Vector<byte[]>();
byte[] firstRecord = readRecord();
records.add(firstRecord);
```

The third line of this code doesn't  put the array into the Vector but instead it puts the reference firstRecord into that Vector. Then if we change the contents of firstRecord after putting it in the vector, what happen is that we change the content of the Vector because we have two references to the same thing.